# Adding user in ubuntu using PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, azure, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to add user to my Ubuntu Virtual Machine (Microsoft Azure) using PHP from another server.

Here is my code.

PHP Code:

```
//including phpseclib
include('Net/SSH2.php');

//Username and Password from form
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

//connecting to azure vm using ssh
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('myservername.cloudapp.net:22');
$ssh->login('myuserid', 'mypassword') or die("Login failed");
$ssh->getServerPublicHostKey();
$cmd = "sudo useradd -d /home/$username -p $(perl -e'print crypt(\"$password\", \"cu\")') $username";
$cmdr = $ssh->exec($cmd);
```

The user is created successfully, but when I login to the server with my newly created username and password using putty it shows "Access Denied"

Kindly help, where am I going wrong?

Comment: what permissions do you have on the file that is executing this code?

Comment: The php file is on my localhost... if you look into my code.. i am logging in to my azure server using my admin-id...

Comment: And the file permission is not the problem... even if i login to my root account and run the command directly in the putty's terminal... i am encountering the same problem... user is created but i can't login..

Comment: i have also noted that if i manually change the password by running "$passwd username" then i am able to login... so my best guess is that there i a problem in the "-p" parameter of the useradd command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It done...!!

Here is the final PHP code

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');

//Username and Password from form
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$salt = "12345678" //any random 8 digit

//connecting to azure vm using ssh
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('myservername.cloudapp.net:22');
$ssh->login('myuserid', 'mypassword') or die("Login failed");
$ssh->getServerPublicHostKey();
$cmd = "sudo useradd -m -p $(mkpasswd -m sha-512 $password $salt) $username";
$cmdr = $ssh->exec($cmd);
```

Solved.!

Answer (score 0):

Allow the user to login using the second command

```
 $cmd = "sudo useradd -d /home/$username -p $(perl -e'print crypt(\"$password\", \"cu\")') $username";
 $cmdr = $ssh->exec($cmd);
 $cmd =  "sudo passwd -u {$username}";
 $cmdr = $ssh->exec($cmd);
```

Comment: I am still encountering the same problem.. "Access Denied"